# RandomizedSearchCV and early_stopping_rounds

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to get the best iteration of `n_estimators` with early stopping and RandomizedSearchCV / GridSearchCV. If I turn on `verbose = True`, I can see the output including the best iteration:

*Early stopping, best iteration is: [852] valid_0's rmse: 0.108495*

However, I haven't been able to figure out how to access it via a command.

Here is my piece of code:

```
%%time

LGBM_model = lgb.LGBMRegressor(n_estimators = 10000)

LGBM_param_Random = {'reg_lambda': [0.01, 0.05],
                      'reg_alpha': [0.01, 0.05],
                      'min_child_samples': randint(1, 50),
                      'subsample': [x / 10 for x in range(1, 10, 1)],  
                      'subsample_freq': randint(1, 100),  
                      'num_leaves': randint(1, 100),
                      'max_depth': list(range(1, 15, 1)),
                      'max_bin': randint(1, 700),
                      'learning_rate': [x / 200 for x in range(1, 10, 1)],
                      'colsample_bytree': [x / 10 for x in range(1, 11, 1)]} 
                        
                    
LGBM_random_grid = RandomizedSearchCV(LGBM_model, LGBM_param_Random, 
                                      cv = CV, verbose = True, 
                                      n_jobs = 7, 
                                      scoring = 'neg_root_mean_squared_error', 
                                      n_iter = 50)

LGBM_fit = LGBM_random_grid.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                                early_stopping_rounds = 200, 
                                eval_set = [[x_test, y_test]], 
                                eval_metric = 'rmse', verbose = True)

round(-1*LGBM_fit.best_score_, 5)
LGBM_fit.best_params_
```

I tried `LGBM_fit.best_iteration` but it threw an error.

Could you please help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `LGBM_fit.best_estimator_.best_iteration_`?

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to the documentation, the best parameters can be obtained using the `best_params_` method of the `RandomizedSearchCV`:

```
LGBM_random_grid.best_params_
```

The best score can be obtained with the `best_score_` method:

```
LGBM_random_grid.best_score_
```

The best model, finally, as:

```
best_model = (LGBM_random_grid.best_estimator_.model)()
```